# Variables added wrongly on all Dataframes of a script - Python 3

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am having 4 Dataframes [(1300,1300) size] in a Python3 script. I would like to include different variables on each one of these dataframes, though now with my code, when I add a new variable to Dataframe #1, this variable is also added on the other dataframes.

How can I solve this error? Is there a connection among dataframes general?

My code is:

```
Dataframe_1 = pd.DataFrame(Dataframe_1, index=names, columns=names)
Dataframe_2 = pd.DataFrame(Dataframe_1, index=names, columns=names)
Dataframe_3 = pd.DataFrame(Dataframe_1, index=names, columns=names)
Dataframe_4 = pd.DataFrame(Dataframe_1, index=names, columns=names)

for r in range(Dataframe_1 .columns.size):
   for c in range(Dataframe_1 .columns.size):
       Dataframe_2.loc[r,c] = jellyfish.hamming_distance(Dataframe_1.index[r],Dataframe_1.columns[c])
       Dataframe_3.loc[r,c] = jellyfish.levenshtein_distance(Dataframe_1.index[r],Dataframe_1.columns[c])
       Dataframe_4.iloc[r,c] = jellyfish.jaro_distance(Dataframe_1.index[r],Dataframe_1.columns[c])
```

Comment: you are refrencing same DataFrame in all 4, it's obvious

Comment: What are your column and index names?

Comment: Maybe try Dataframe_2 = Dataframe_1.copy()

Comment: @busybear The index name and column names of each Dataframe are strings retrieved from a database table. e.g. my index/column name has strings such as "Machinery E52",etc.

Comment: @shaun I need to keep the reference to the same Dataframe, because it is the one that I need in order to calculate the distances between the two strings